# how to access the value of input text was nested in ui-grid cell

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT59p.png)

I made a cell template(ui-grid) which contains a label, a textfield, and a button. I bind a ng-click on the button. But I dont know how to access the value of textfield. Because what I want to implement is when user input value in the field and click save imagebutton and it will call ajax then do some update in web service.

I was wondering that is it possible to access the textfield from row entity, but I could not find the textfield property in the grid-cell.

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

ui-grid has built in row editor features. Try the link below.

http://brianhann.com/create-a-modal-row-editor-for-ui-grid-in-minutes/